# why init process can't create dynamically?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, archlinux

As per my understanding init process which is the first user-space process starting in Linux is created staticall in `arch/ia64/kernel/init_task.c`.

Why we can't create this init process also dynamically? slab allocator is available once the kernel is up, so we can get a task_struct from slab allocator and create init process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the `init_task` with type `struct task_struct *` is defined in arch/*/kernel/init_task.c files. This struct is used early in start_kernel: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/init/main.c?v=3.10#L471

```
471 asmlinkage void __init start_kernel(void)
472 {

481         smp_setup_processor_id();

489         cgroup_init_early();

498         boot_cpu_init();
499         page_address_init();
500         pr_notice("%s", linux_banner);
501         setup_arch(&command_line);
502         mm_init_owner(&init_mm, &init_task);
```

So, slab allocator may be available at moment of `init` starting, but the task_struct of the init is used earlier, both in start_kernel and in other places (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=3.10&i=init_task) e.g. to **statically** init the current_task pointer on other CPUs.

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/common.c?v=3.10#L1080

```
1084 DEFINE_PER_CPU(struct task_struct *, current_task) ____cacheline_aligned =
1085         &init_task;
```

Comment: Can you please tell me why mm_init_owner is required inside start_kernel(). I could see following definition for mm_init_owner() in kernel/fork.c.                                                                      `void mm_init_owner(struct mm_struct *mm, struct task_struct *p)
{
        mm->owner = p;
}`

Comment: mm_init_owner is only one of many usages of init_task. There are other, and it can be hard to change current_task initialization from static to dynamic.

Comment: mm_init_owner is only one of many usages of init_task? can you please explain a bit more, because I could see mm_init_owner() is assigning owner member of mm_struct to task_struct.                                           <code>                                                                                                void mm_init_owner(struct mm_struct *mm, struct task_struct *p) { mm->owner = p; }                                                                                            <\code>